# Is it true that $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{b}f(x,y)dy=\int_{a}^{b}\frac{d}{dx}f(x,y)dy?$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

1. Is it always true that $\frac d {dx}\int_a^b f(x,y)\, dy = \int_a^b \frac{d}{dx}f(x,y)\,dy$, where domains are Euclidean space and $a$ and $b$ are allowed to be $\pm\infty$? This is widely used in many contexts but I don't think I've seen any proof regarding this. Would there be any case where one of the terms diverges but the other converges? If so, what is the condition to guarantee the above integrals are the same?
2. Another question is... if we want to evaluate $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty\left| a_{m,n}\right|$, is it eligible to write $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \left| a_{m,n} \right| = \sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \left| a_{m,n} \right|$$
   in the middle of my solution? I'm hesitant because we cannot normally say $\infty=\infty$ so without knowing that the above sum converges, we cannot switch the order. On the other hand, we have the theorem that says that if one of the sums above in the equality exists, two terms must be the same.

Could anybody give me any insight? Thank you so much!!

Comment: 1. is called the "Leibniz integral rule", a.k.a. "Feynman's trick".  2. Yes, OK for nonnegative double sums, even if the value is $+\infty$.  See Tonelli's theorem for a generalization to measure theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question is answered in [this wikipedia article.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) The second is answered [here.](http://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Efeldman/m321/twosum.pdf)

Comment: Thanks! Actually.. it doesn't address my second question, but I guess I can just assume that they are the same